# How to clear Pillow error: *** Error creating a JP2 color space: falling back to sRGB

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I am making a command line application that needs to grab images from the system clipboard, achieving it through

```
from PIL import ImageGrab

prevImg = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
```

however, whenever I call `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` pillow prints the error message

```
*** Error creating a JP2 color space: falling back to sRGB
```

---

There doesn't seem to be any problem reading the images, but whenever I call the function, this error message is printed.

I've tried redirecting stderr to null but that does not do it.

Is there any way to either resolve or suppress the error messages?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is probably generated by the Python `logger` module that PIL often uses to log errors.

So, you probably need to get the logger it is using and change the logging level to something higher like `logging.CRITICAL` or `logging.WARNING`. Logging is described nicely [here](https://pymotw.com/3/logging/index.html).

I haven't looked into this too much (because I don't get that error) but after importing `PIL`, you probably need something like:

```
from PIL import Image
import logging

PILlogger = logging.getLogger('PIL')
PILlogger.setLevel(logging.CRITICAL)
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ImageGrab.grabclipboard()` method for MacOS uses an Apple script command to get the image from the clipboard. It is done by calling the separate process using `subprocess.call(..)`.

There is a workaround to disable the output for all subprocess calls:

```
def disable_subprocess_output():
    subprocess_call_original = subprocess.call

    def subprocess_call_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        default_kwargs = {
            'stdout': subprocess.DEVNULL,
            'stderr': subprocess.DEVNULL
        }
        kwargs.update(default_kwargs)
        return subprocess_call_original(*args, **kwargs)

    subprocess.call = subprocess_call_wrapper

disable_subprocess_output()
```